# Significance test for accuracy - normal assumption

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, normality-assumption

I have a dataset with pre-defined labels. I trained two machine learning classifier methods A and B to predict the labels and calculated the accuracy for each. I varied the dataset a bit and thus got multiple experiments with multiple accuracy results. I calculated the mean and the variance for the accuracy values of the classifier methods: $m_A, m_B, v_A, v_B$.

I want to perform a significance test using p-values. For that I need to assume a distribution for the accuracy. For example if I assume that the accuracy values for method A are normal distributed and the $m_B$ is not in the range of $m_A\pm 1.92 \cdot v_A$, then is I can reject the null hypothesis with at least 0.05 confidence that method B has the same accuracy as method A.

But is my assumption that the accuracy is normal distributed correct?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from the limited information given.  Usually people look at the data to assess the plausibility of a Normality assumption.  What do a Normal probability plot or a histogram of your data look like?

Comment: @whuber: 1. Honestly, if I look at a graph/histogram, I cannot tell the difference between a Gaussian, and a t-distribution even for few degrees of freedom. 2. I made about a 100 datasets and plotted them and got s.th. that looked like two Gaussian bell curves - one after the other. I am sure I did s.th. wrong during the experimentation configuration - not sure what though.

Comment: I thought there is some rule of thumb regarding how accuracy is distributed. From https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6790639 I can infer that the t-distribution seems to be right - but I am not sure whether my inference is correct here.